# Why are the Shabbat additions to Pesukei D'zimra added before the every-day parts?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, priorities

In the Pesukei D'zimra of Shabbat, why are the Shabbat-specific portions added before most of the every-day portions? Shouldn't they be said after according to the rule: *Tadir V'she'eino Tadir, Tadir Kodem* (when there's a common requirement and a rare requirement, the common requirement comes first)?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose and structure of *Pesukei D'Zimra* is outlined in *Shulchan Aruch*, but the basic idea is that it all leads up to *Ashrei*, and specifically the *Posuk* פותח את ידך. The things that come after that have a specific purpose (finishing until the end of tehillim, and so on - but mainly about providing praise to Hashem and the types of praises, leading up to *Yishtabach* which expresses that concept).

So in terms of the structure of Pesukei D'Zimra, some of the things that we add on Shabbos are additional meditations intended to be before *Ashrei* (broadly - about Hashem's creation and control of the world), whereas what is added afterwards (before *Yishtabach*) is about the idea of praising Hashem. So within their respective sections of *Pesukei D'Zimra*, they are at the end, following the principle of *Tadir Vshe'eino Tadir, Tadir Kodem*.

Comment: Where exactly in Shulchan Aruch is this thematic schema laid out?